# Why do I need an internet connection to rename my Magikarp?

Tags: magikarp-jump

Any time I name a new Magikarp in Magikarp Jump, a screen briefly pops with "[Now Transmitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osf9Q.png)" before I can continue playing.

As an experiment, I tried turning off my cellular data. When I went to rename my Magikarp, I was shown an error telling me to "*[Please check your connection and try again a little later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhtdN.png).*"

**Why do I need an internet connection to rename my Magikarp? Where is my Magikarp's nickname being sent?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The game is checking if your Magikarp's name contains swears, profanity, or other prohibited language.

If your Magikarp's name contains any prohibited words, you will be prompted to choose a different name.

Based on personal testing and a list from [/r/MagikarpJump](https://www.reddit.com/r/MagikarpJump/comments/6hqhzc/bannedcensored_magikarp_names/?ref=share&ref_source=link), blacklisted names include:

> <sub>*Boob, Butt, Dick, Tit, Ass, Shit, Bitch, Shine, Depression, Melon<sup>1</sup>, Event, Poop, Weed, Kush, Muff, Murder, Zahar, Gay, GoldenShower,* and *Olaf*.</sub>
>  
>  <sub><sup>1</sup> Bizarrely, while ***Melon*** is banned, ***Melons***, ***Watermelon***, and ***Water Melon*** are perfectly acceptable.</sub>

[image: Error: Name uses prohibited language]

Comment: Admit it - you only made this Q+A so you could legitimately use profanity without getting flagged. :D

Comment: Also, why is Olaf a banned name? That doesn't sound that offensive to me.

Comment: @MageXy Or other things, like "event". There's probably some sort of inside joke with Olaf.